# Why do i get a NZEC Error while submitting my code?

Tags: python

```
x=float(input())
y=float(input())
if x>y:
    print(format(y,'.2f'))
elif x%5!=0:
    print(format(y,'.2f'))
else:
    balance=y-(x+0.5)
    print(format(balance,'.2f'))
```

This code is giving me a NZEC Error. How to get rid of it

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Which version of python are you running? I am not able to replicate on Python 3.5

Comment: IDE Version-Python 3.6(Online Code chef IDE itself)

Comment: @mousetail The error comes only when i submit my code .It doesn't show the error when I run the code .The code runs fine.